# mocha-casperjs headless testing: document.contains undefined

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, casperjs

In using mocha-casperjs to test our web app in development:

"document" console.logs as  [object HTMLDocument]
but document.contains logs as undefined.

causing the app's javascript to:
Error:    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.contains(item)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `document.contains` is a non-standard thing from internet explorer. Don't use it. [Use `document.body.contains` instead.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document)